# Is automating App Registration on Azure possible through ARM Template on the User's tenant?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-function-app

I am trying to deploy a solution as a managed application through ARM Template. For the deployment to work, I need the Client Id and Client Secret of a registered Application along with the Tenant Id.

In my previous scope, I was assuming that the user would have an existing App Registered but now I want to Automate the App registration process for the user and be able to register an application having O365 API Permissions in user's tenant.

Below is the approach I were following earlier.

[image: Earlier Approach]

So unlike above approach, I am now trying to create either a Web Application or a Function Application which would authenticate the User and register the Application for them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

ARM Template is used to create Azure resources under Azure subscription. But App Registration is the resource of Azure AD module. They are two different areas.

A similar discussion [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51914) for your reference.

You can use Azure AD Powershell to create the Azure AD app and create the client secret by using [New-AzureADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) and [New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Anyone did this via ARM?

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing a similar problem and seems that ARM deployment scripts may be the answer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template

this post gives an example on how to create app registrations with ARM deployment scripts:

https://moimhossain.com/2020/04/03/azure-ad-app-via-arm-template-deployment-scripts/

Comment: Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep

Comment: Quickstart template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.resources/deployment-script-azcli-graph-azure-ad

Comment: It is not e2e guideline. Manual action is required of granting user assigned identity proper rights.